# Internal applications consoleapp, uddi, wlstestclient not deployed by default during installation of Weblogic Server 10.3 on Windows

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x

Thanks in advance for your time. I need to explain a little bit of the background before I get to my issue so thanks again for reading.

After installing the Windows version of Weblogic 10.3 and deploying my application on my localhost, I started up the server. 
So when I startup the server, the console says non-critical internal application **uddi** was not deployed, so was **consoleapp** and **wlstestclient**.

> > BEA-149617 Non-critical internal application wlstestclient was not deployed. Error: [Deployer:149158] No application files exist at 'wlstestclient'.

According to Webogic docs, these are to be expected:

> **BEA-149617** 
>   Warning: Non-critical internal application *name* was not deployed.
>
> > **Error**: message Description Internal Application *name* was not deployed.      Application may not have been installed. 
> >     **Cause**: 
> >      Internal Application may not have been installed. 
> >     **Action**: 
> >      Install WLS internal Application by running WLS installer and choosing the relevent option.

Now, I already have Weblogic8.1 on my machine, so I copied uddi.war and its properties from the server/lib directory and got around the first issue. 
I also have Weblogic10.3 installed in a whole different location (this is used with simple Eclipse not Weblogic Workshop, for a totally different project). Since they are both the same version, I copied the consoleapp and console-ext directories from server/lib and put them under this server's server/lib.

So when I restart Weblogic, it does find consoleapp when I point to http://localhost:7001/console and actually tries to deploy it the first time. However, I get a 503 - Service unavailable. From the stacktrace, basically it looks like it couldn't load the console webapp. 
In other words, my trial for hacking it did not work :(

When I checked again on the Oracle site, I see 2 exes for Weblogic Workshop 10.3 on Windows:
Oracle Workshop for WebLogic 10.3 - Net Installer & Oracle Workshop for WebLogic 10.3 - Package Installer. I had used Package installer the first time.  Should I be using Net installer? What is the difference? The package installer is bigger in size, they are both 32 bit which is what I have.

I am trying to not uninstall and reinstall - but is that my only option? Any ideas how I can get consoleapp to deploy? I have not used WLS installer before.. any gotchas there? Thanks again for your time.

Regards, veeCan

Answer (score 0):

I guess I asked too soon. Should have spent more time looking for it in the docs. Oh well.

Posting the link for others' benefit - Thanks for reading.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/getstart/overview.html#wp1062917

Regards,
veeCan